# Automount of NTFS USB partitions on Gnome fails if device name is sdb (FAT32 is OK)

Tags: debian, gnome, usb-drive, automounting, ntfs-3g

When I plug a USB storage device (i.e. USB key) on my computer with Gnome, the filesystems available on the device are automatically mounted (in `/media/<partition-label>`), and a file explorer (`nautilus`) popup appears showing the device content.

However, **this automounting does not work with NTFS filesystems**.

On various forums, people suggest to set ntfs-3g SUID root :

```
# chmod u+s /usr/bin/ntfs-3g
```

This does not solve the problem, here is the popup message:

```
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
Error opening '/dev/sdb2': Permission denied
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Permission denied
Please check '/dev/sdb2' and the ntfs-3g binary permissions,
and the mounting user ID. More explanation is provided at
http://ntfs-3g.org/support.html#unprivileged [=> DEAD LINK]
```

However, since I have all necessary rights (I'm on the "floppy" group which has *read/write* permission on `/dev/sdb1`), I can mount the filesystem myself:

```
$ ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /home/me/mymount
```

How can I achieve this automounting with NTFS filesystems? Avoiding, if possible, changing `/etc/fstab`.

I'm currently using Debian 6.0 (Squeeze).

EDIT: 
Also, I just noticed a strange behavior: when there is already a `sdbX` mounted filesystem, I plug my NTFS USB device (as `sdc`...), and everything works as expected, automount works. But not if the device name is `sdb`...

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -ld /dev/sdb*` when the drive isn't plugged in, as well as `grep -r sdb /etc/udev/rules.d ~/.gconf`

Comment: @Gilles both commands return no result when the drive is not plugged... One more detail : I have two NTFS partitions on the device.